# Javascript array return "a"?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I wrote this piece with expectancy to store name and score in each and every array element.

**Expected output:**

```
 var students = [
    ['David', 80],
    ['Dane', 77],
    ['Dick', 88],
    ['Donald', 95],
    ['Dean', 68]
    ];
```

However, I stumble upon assigning the second value in an array element... In codepen.io, the value returned is "a".

**HTML:**

```html
name: <input type="text" id="namebox"><br><br>
score: <input type="text" id="scorebox"><br><br>

<input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addStudent()">

<input type="button" value="Display" onclick="displayArray()">
```

**Javascript:**

```
var x = 0;
var students = [];

function addStudent(){
    students[x] = document.getElementById("namebox").value;
    students[x][1] = document.getElementById("scorebox").value;
    alert(students[x] + " added");
    x++;
    document.getElementById("namebox").value = "";
    document.getElementById("scorebox").value = "";
    document.getElementById("namebox").focus();
    document.getElementById("scorebox").focus();
}

function displayArray(){
    var e = "<hr>";

    for (y = 0; y < students.length; y++)
    {
        e += students[y] + students[y][1] + "<br>";
    }
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = e;
}
```

Comment: students[x][0] = document.getElementById("namebox").value;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as suggested by @Y.C. if you add `students[x][0] = document.getElementById("namebox").value;` your code will work. I wanna propose just a minor modification though so that your json array keeps its "pattern". Enclose `document.getElementById("scorebox").value` in `parseInt()` so you get the score as a number. In other words just write `parseInt(document.getElementById("scorebox").value);`

**UPDATE**

since my previous suggestion only works if you predefine the array I editted the code so now this should work.

instead of assigning the value to each cell I used push() function so now the addStudent method looks like this:

```
function addStudent(){
  students.push(document.getElementById("namebox").value, parseInt(document.getElementById("scorebox").value));
alert(students[x] + " added");
x++;
document.getElementById("namebox").value = "".focus();
document.getElementById("scorebox").value = "".focus();
document.getElementById("namebox").focus();
document.getElementById("scorebox").focus();
}
```

**UPDATE #2**

my last update was only for addStudent to work since I thought this was the problem. So now this whole thing has to work by following the steps below:

on your html add a div with the id result because it seems that you forgot

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

on your Javascript just copy and paste the following

```
var x = 0;
var students = [];

    function addStudent(){
      students.push([document.getElementById("namebox").value, parseInt(document.getElementById("scorebox").value)]);
    alert(students[x] + " added");
    x++;
    document.getElementById("namebox").value = "".focus();
    document.getElementById("scorebox").value = "".focus();
    document.getElementById("namebox").focus();
    document.getElementById("scorebox").focus();
    }

    function displayArray(){
    var e = "<hr>";

    for (y = 0; y < students.length; y++)
    {
    e += students[y][0] + "&nbsp;" + students[y][1] + "<br>";
    }
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = e;
    }
```

Notice that I have changed the addStudent function a bit just to add every student as a seperate array consisted of his/her name and his/her score.

Comment: @AhQuan take a look at my codepen, it works, unless I completely misunderstood your problem http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rjLPLB?editors=1111

Comment: ya because u predefined the array already, if it is created blank, the insertion won't work =(

Comment: I see, ok I editted the code both to codepen and my answer so now I think your problem is solved @AhQuan .

Comment: it still won't, the display function will not work =(

Comment: @AhQuan I updated my answer so now everything works. Let me know if everything is ok now :)

Comment: THANKS A LOT catchiecop! =D

Comment: No problem feel free to mark the answer as correct for future reference :)

Comment: but may I ask what is the reason behind this? I mean the values having to be separated individual arrays.. =/ thanks mate!

Comment: You mean the reason for pushing the values in the students array as ["name", score] ?

Comment: ya ya, why can they only be pushed as arrays, and why if not, the values returned are weird

Comment: Oh just so that there is the same pattern as the array you gave in your question. It is more organized that way in my opinion. You could also pass them as a unified array like ['david', 20, 'sally', 40] and extract the names by getting the odd values and scores by getting the even values

Answer (score 1):

do something like this

```
function addStudent(){
    var studentArray = [],
        tempArray = [],
        index= 0;

    tempArray[0] = document.getElementById("namebox").value; // David
    tempArray[1] = document.getElementById("scorebox").value; //80

     // this will insert array into main array.
    studentArray.push(tempArray); // [['David', 80]]

    // rest of your code

    return studentArray;
    }
```